# Wrong Parameters error after call opcode in Assembly 8086 (emulator8086)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm trying to make a function (procedure) in Assembly x86 but for some reason the call opcode gives me the "wring parameters" error

```
; <somecode>

    call max   ; --> gives an error

    int 0x16
    ret

max proc:  

; <some code>

    ret
max endp
```

I don't see the problem here but I might be missing something.
What's the cause for this error?

Comment: I think the trailing `:` on `max proc:` looks suspicious.  `proc` declarations aren't labels.  I don't know why the error would show up on a call to it, unless it's for an undefined symbol, but EMU8086's built-in assembler is not very good.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, that is the case. removing the ':' after proc fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The trailing `:` on `max proc:`** is your problem. `proc` declarations aren't labels like `foo:`

I don't know why the error would show up on a `call` to it, unless it's for an undefined symbol, but EMU8086's built-in assembler is not very good.